# Prove that $\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln \left(\frac{(1+\sin x)^{1+\cos x}}{1+\cos x}\right)dx = 0$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

> Prove that
>
> $$
> I=\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln \left(\frac{(1+\sin x)^{1+\cos x}}{1+\cos x}\right)\;dx = 0
> $$

**My Attempt:**

$$
\begin{align}
I &= \int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln(1+\sin x)^{1+\cos x}\;dx-\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln(1+\cos x)\;dx\\
&=\int_{0}^{2\pi}(1+\cos x)\cdot \ln(1+\sin x)\;dx-\int_{0}^{2\pi}\ln(1+\cos x)\;dx\\
&= \int_{0}^{2\pi}(1+\cos x)\cdot \ln(1+\sin x)\;dx - 2\int_{0}^{\pi}\ln(1+\cos x)\;dx
\end{align}
$$

How can I complete the solution from this point?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
&\int_0^{2\pi}\log\left(\frac{(1+\sin(x))^{1+\cos(x)}}{1+\cos(x)}\right)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\left[(1+\cos(x))\log(1+\sin(x))-\log(1+\cos(x))\right]\,\mathrm{d}x\tag{1}\\
&=\color{#C00000}{\int_0^{2\pi}\log(1+\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x-\int_0^{2\pi}\log(1+\cos(x))\,\mathrm{d}x}\\
&+\color{#00A000}{\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(x)\log(1+\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x}\tag{2}\\
&=\color{#C00000}{0}+\color{#00A000}{\int_0^{2\pi}\log(1+\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}(1+\sin(x))}\tag{3}\\
&=\int_1^1\log(u)\,\mathrm{d}u\tag{4}\\[9pt]
&=0\tag{5}
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: properties of $\log$
$(2)$: redistributing pieces
$(3)$: the red integrals cancel using $\cos(x)=\sin(x+\pi/2)$
$(4)$: substitute $u=1+\sin(x)$
$(5)$: integral that ends where it starts is $0$

---

Alternatively, note that
$$
\begin{align}
\cos(x)\log(1+\sin(x))
&=\cos(u+\pi/2)\log(1+\sin(u+\pi/2))\\
&=-\sin(u)\log(1+\cos(u))
\end{align}
$$
is an odd function of $u$. Therefore, because the integral of an odd function is $0$, we get by the substitution $x=u+\pi/2$,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^{2\pi}\cos(x)\log(1+\sin(x))\,\mathrm{d}x
&=-\int_0^{2\pi}\sin(u)\log(1+\cos(u))\,\mathrm{d}u\\
&=-\int_{-\pi}^\pi\sin(u)\log(1+\cos(u))\,\mathrm{d}u\\[6pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$

Comment: Would you mind explaining how the integral nullifying each other?

Comment: I have added some explanation. Let me know if that is not enough.

Answer (score 5):

Using the last step of your work, we have
$$
\int_0^{\large2\pi}\ln(1+\sin x)\ dx+\int_0^{\large2\pi}\ln(1+\sin x)\cdot\cos x\ dx-\int_0^{\large2\pi}\ln(1+\cos x)\ dx.
$$
By symmetry, we obtain
$$
\int_0^{\large2\pi}\ln(1+\sin x)\ dx=\int_0^{\large2\pi}\ln(1+\cos x)\ dx.
$$
Letting $y=1+\sin x$ the middle integral turns out to be
$$
\int_{x=0}^{\large2\pi}\ln(1+\sin x)\cdot\cos x\ dx=\int_{y=1}^{1}\ln y\ dy=0.
$$

---

**Addendum :**

Consider the plot of $\ln(1+\sin x)\cdot\cos x$ for $0<x<2\pi$,

[image]

then, by symmetry,
$$
\int_{x=0}^{\large2\pi}\ln(1+\sin x)\cdot\cos x\ dx=0.
$$

Comment: Some things can be made clear with a plot, but I am wary of judging exact cancellation this way. However, it can be shown that the function is odd about $x=\pi/2$, which does verify the cancellation hinted at in the graph.

Comment: @robjohn Truth be told, I am even not sure about this answer since I made it in hurry. Clearly, the answer is not my typical style. I've deleted this before but I decided to post it.

Comment: The first part of the answer is correct (+1), but without proving the symmetry of the plot, I would avoid using the plot as justification.

Answer (score 5):

Let's make use of the general fact that, when integrating over an entire period, the sine and cosine functions are interchangeable, as are their signs, i.e., for **any** function of two variables, we have

$$\int_0^{2\pi}f(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi}f(\sin\theta,\cos\theta)d\theta$$
and
$$\int_0^{2\pi}f(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)d\theta = \int_0^{2\pi}f(-\cos\theta,\sin\theta)d\theta=\int_0^{2\pi}f(\cos\theta,-\sin\theta)d\theta$$

Thus

$$I=\int_0^{2\pi}\log\left({(1+\sin\theta)^{1+\cos\theta}\over1+\cos\theta} \right)d\theta$$
implies

$$\begin{align}
2I&=\int_0^{2\pi}\left[\log\left({(1+\sin\theta)^{1+\cos\theta}\over1+\cos\theta} \right)+\log\left({(1+\sin\theta)^{1-\cos\theta}\over1-\cos\theta} \right)\right]d\theta\\
&=\int_0^{2\pi}\log\left({(1+\sin\theta)^2\over(1+\cos\theta)(1-\cos\theta)} \right)d\theta\\
&=2\int_0^{2\pi}\log(1+\sin\theta)d\theta-\int_0^{2\pi}\log(1+\cos\theta)d\theta-\int_0^{2\pi}\log(1-\cos\theta)d\theta\\
&=2\int_0^{2\pi}\log(1+\cos\theta)d\theta-\int_0^{2\pi}\log(1+\cos\theta)d\theta-\int_0^{2\pi}\log(1+\cos\theta)d\theta\\
&=0
\end{align}$$

Comment: (+1) Nice approach. The cancellation you mention is very similar to the cancellation in the alternative approach I just added to my answer while you were writing this up.